# Summing by common strings in different files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, numeric-data

I have a file `file1` with the amount of times a user shows up in the files, something like this:

```
4 userC
2 userA
1 userB
```

and I have another file `file2` with users and other info like:

```
userC, degree2
userA, degree1
userB, degree2
```

and I want an output where it shows the amount of times user shows up, for each degree:

```
5 degree2
2 degree1
```

Comment: I'm pretty much blocked, I have no idea of what to try :/ and yes, it has to be in shell only. from what I know I either use and awk, and I don't know how to, or I use a for with an if.

Comment: Look at `join`.

Comment: The thing is, i still haven't learnt join, which means i can't use it, so i think i'll either have to use an awk or a cicle.

Comment: `awk` would be perfect for this. There are already a number of questions here with this same concept (but without the summing, which would be easy enough to add). Read [tag:awk].

Comment: If you can use `awk` it really means it doesn't have to be in shell. "In shell" would mean using shell **only** and nothing else. Which of course could be done, at least with those that have support for associative arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[, ]' 'NR==FNR{n[$2]=$1;next}{m[$3]+=n[$1]}
    END{for(i in m){print i " " m[i]}}' \
    file1 file2
degree1 2
degree2 5
```

Or you can put it into a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 
BEGIN {
    FS="[, ]"
}
{
    if (NR == FNR) {
        n[$2] = $1;
        next;
    } else {
        m[$3] += n[$1];
    }
}
END {
    for (i in m) {
        print i " " m[i];
    }
}
```

First set field separator to both comma and space (that is the `BEGIN` block or the `-F` command line option.

Then, when parsing the first file (the `FNR == NR` idiom) put number of connections for a user into array indexed by user name. When parsing the following file(s), add the number of connections for each user into the array indexed by user group.

Finally (the `END` block) scan the whole array and print the key, value pairs.

Comment: I'm not really sure what this did, but for some reason it only printed out a number.

Comment: @GuyWhoNeedsHelp Which number?

Comment: printed 3, i think it's the m[i]

Comment: Did you check it on example files from your question or some other files?

Comment: the files i used have the same layout as the ones in the example the only difference is i use the actual user name and degree name

Comment: @GuyWhoNeedsHelp please create files as in your example from the question and check. I can only help you with stuff which you posted.

Comment: tried with the exact files i used on the example and it printed 7, so it printed the amount of all users

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, maybe you are using some strange awk version. I've tested with GNU Awk 4.0.2.

Comment: +1 Nicely done. Works for me (GNU Awk 4.0.1) under both the GNU and the compatibility (`-c`) modes.

Comment: for you the awk command you wrote as an answer worked?

Comment: @John1024 thank you for reminder of `-c` option. @GuyWhoNeedsHelp yes it works for me with both `gawk` and `awk -c` (when gawk behaves as traditional UNIX awk, without any extensions and so on).

Comment: ah i made it work, but how would i write the command awk if i didn't have the comma in file2?

Comment: @GuyWhoNeedsHelp You don't have a comas in your original files? So why did you include them to the question example in the first place? Changing `m[$3]` to `m[$2]` probably will do the trick, but without seeing example hard to guess.

Comment: yeah,it worked, thank you so much, you saved my life

Comment: @jimmij next time please consider explaining how the script goes about doing what it does. And feel free to change my change - I might have gotten something wrong. Also it is IMHO a good idea to split long lines - it increases readability a lot. It is no longer a one-liner, but much more understandable. :)